# Trying to connect history to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component of a route that I have gone to.

This child component submits a back dispatch.

I feel like I should be able to do the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Back extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
    }

    goBack() {
        this.props.history.goBack();
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div className="linkback" onClick={this.goBack}>
             <div className="triangle" />
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, null)(Back);
```

However, when I try to view this.props and this.props.history, I get {} and undefined respectively.

What else do I have to do to pass the route down? I am using Connected Router.

Do I need to actually pass the location down to the child component directly? Is this what merge is for?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get the question. But Are u saying `this.props.history` is undefined ? In that case, have you tried passing down the props from parent component to child component. Or Wrap with `withRouter` ?

Comment: Shouldn't connect() do the work of withRouter for Connected Router? Or am I wrong about that?